# Xcode 4.2 does not commit files?

Tags: ios, svn, xcode4.2

I have Xcode 4.2 and I was working ona a project, that was commited previously with - let;s call it - place A. Then I copied it on my disk to another place, made modifications and now I imported via Xcode Organizer whole new project into place B. But when I checked out project from place B I cannot commit any file. I select a file, choose commit, write comment and go. It looks ok, but in fact the status of this file is not changing, so I can without any warning make commits on and on... Is it problem with some project setting or what? I remember that in previous Xcode in project settings you could set svn location, but here I don't see anything like it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not copied a folder **.svn** in the root of your Project - there are the meta-informations of SVN, without this infos SVN can not work. Just find and copy this folder from A to B and the issue will gone!